# Convert from tuple to string, untuplify

Tags: python

```
def untuplify(tpl):
    return map(lambda x: str(x), tpl)
```

I can't get the output for `untuplify((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))` which is `12345`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> def untuplify(tpl):
...     return "".join(map(str, tpl))
... 
>>> untuplify((1,2,3,4))
'1234'
>>>
```

The reason you're getting unexpected output is because `map()` returns a list. `str.join()` is the canonical way of joining strings from a sequence into a single string.

Comment: You might want to add a call to `int`.

Comment: Question says *tuple to string*

Comment: You're right. There is a mismatch between the question title and the description.